# Javascript Date format with Google Drive REST API

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I have a problem when trying to formate date from Google Drive REST API... When I get **`createdDate`** from api, it will showing `2015-10-12T03:38:15.813Z`

How to change format  from `2015-10-12T03:38:15.813Z` to `12 October 2015` ???

### My Code :

```js
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B3hR6CXw7JStd3JaMFljTzRyOGc?key=AIzaSyDoMD79fdW7fC8SOlgxFIH5bxTn2EBQ87E",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {
            $('#date').text(result.createdDate);
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='date'></span>
```

Comment: Try to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), it is a really nice library to work with dates.

Comment: can you give me an example by using `moment.js` ??

Comment: something like moment("2015-10-12T03:38:15.813Z").format("DD MMMM YYYY")

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery datepicker like this.

```
var date=yourdate.substr(0, yourdate.indexOf('T');
$.datepicker.formatDate('M dd, yy', new Date(date);
```